How to handle sessions after Chrome's planned cross-site cookie changes?
I have a web app that runs React on the frontend, like the title suggests, it has a login/authentication feature which is powered by session cookies, however, due to the frontend and backend being hosted on seperate domains, the session cookie the backend sets can only be used by the frontend using the SameSite option set to none, sending credentials back and forth.
This works fine, however, Chrome is now stating that it is planning to deprecate cross-site cookies, which will break the auth system for various sites.
What is the recommended alternative for legacy sites?

Still looking for suggestions.
